# Nested lambda expressions are very slow to compile and generate huge object file by Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, lambda, compiler-bug

I find that nested lambda expressions are very slow to compile and generate huge .obj files. For example, on my computer, the following code generates a obj file of size 4766 KB:

```
int main()
{
  auto f = []
  {
    auto f = []
    {
      auto f = []
      {
        auto f = []
        {
          auto f = []
          {
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}
```

And the following code (one more nesting level is added) will cause a [C1128](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8578y171.aspx) error.

```
int main()
{
  auto f = []
  {
    auto f = []
    {
      auto f = []
      {
        auto f = []
        {
          auto f = []
          {
            auto f = []
            {
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
}
```

Also, they are very slow to compile. Is there any explanation for this? I'm using Visual C++ 2013.

## Update

This seems to be a bug in Visual C++, I've reported it to Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813755/nested-lambdas-in-visual-c-2013-are-very-slow-to-compile-and-generate-huge-object-file.

Comment: First one seems to run relatively fast on [rextester](http://rextester.com/IFZY62757) and also `gcc` and `clang`. The second code snippet does not seem to work though on rextester.

Comment: VS2013 is a bit broken possibly: See here: https://gist.github.com/aras-p/8333398

Comment: What is the question? This seems to be a bug in VC++ 2013, please report it.

Comment: So VC++ is not very good at this then?

Comment: C# developers tend to write the whole program in one operator with 1000 lambda expressions. Maybe it is good that writing such terrible code is currently impossible with VC++ ...

Comment: You should submit a [bug report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzszcehe.aspx#bkmk_reportabug) and add the link to the question.

Comment: Even it is a bug, what problem are you solving by having that many nested lambdas ?

Comment: @Jagannath agreed I don't see a clear use but it does violate their documentation and it is definitely pathological the way the compile time increases with the levels of nesting. So even if this feature is not directly useful it points to problems in the implementation that should be fixed.

Comment: @Jagannath It's not some particular problems I want to solve. I found the problem in some test code. I want to know if it's my problem. Maybe someday I'll need to write a bunch of nested lambdas.

Comment: The bug report has an updated on `2/16` which said a fix was put in for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how useful such deeply nested lambdas are but for what it is worth as far as I can tell this is a bug, the [Visual Studio compiler limits document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft39hh4x.aspx) states (*emphasis mine*):

> The C++ standard recommends limits for various language constructs. The following is a list of constructs where the Visual C++ compiler does not implement the recommended limits. The **first number is the recommended limit and the second number is the limit implemented by Visual C++**:

and includes the following bullet:

> **Nesting levels of compound statements**, iteration control structures, and selection control structures **[256] (256)**.

If we look at the grammar in the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) *compound-statement* will eventually get back to *primary-expression* which includes *lambda-expression*. So Visual Studio should support up to `256` levels of nesting.

You could also see this by looking at the grammar for *lambda-expression*  which is as follows:

> lambda-introducer lambda-declarator<sub>opt</sub> **compound-statement**

The [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) has a set of recommend limits in *Annex B* but they are *only guidelines and do not determine compliance*.

**Update**

The [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813755/nested-lambdas-in-visual-c-2013-are-very-slow-to-compile-and-generate-huge-object-file) the OP filed was updated recently to indicate this will be fixed in a future release.

Comment: @EFanZh I don't see any other way to look at this as other than a bug, you should really submit this as a bug report. There are several lambda related bugs but none that seem to match this.

Comment: I've reported it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/813755/nested-lambdas-in-visual-c-2013-are-very-slow-to-compile-and-generate-huge-object-file.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling your second examaple gives:

```
$ time cl x.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

x.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:x.exe
x.obj

real    0m0.764s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.140s
```

The size is

```
$ ls -lh x.exe
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lt None 118K 14. Jan 16:33 x.exe
```

I don't see any problems.

Comment: It is probably machine dependent, on [rextester](http://rextester.com/XLDN91603) I have to add more nesting to get it to timeout which means is ran more than 30 seconds. Experimenting with nesting levels show a noticeable increase in time for each nesting level added before the timeout period.